# What are example cases in which I should use Python in UiPath?

Tags: python, uipath

I am trying to determine why I would have the need to use Python in UiPath vs invoking VB.Net code. If someone could provide specific examples about why using Python would be more beneficial, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I am a java + python developer and to use UiPath have to google vb.net syntaxes. I guess if you are at Guru level in python and don't want to struggle (being new) with vb.net that should be enough reason for using Python in UiPath. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is my assumption as well. I was wondering if someone knew of a special case in which python would be more beneficial. I am a new UIPath developer, and I am very comfortable with python, so I wanted to make a case for my boss as to why I could/should use python over vb.net which is what the UIPath framework uses. UIPath has python activities to call python code, but the company I work for doesn’t have python installed on any of the machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a larger user community than VB.Net, therefore it is more likely to get help with Python in case you need to find out how to do something or have a problem.

It would be more comfortable if UIPath allowed writing the expressions in Python, but it's not dramatic either. You can always call a thread written in your favorite language and get the results to continue with the UIPath flow. Actually the expressions that one writes in UIPath are not so complex.